# Ubuntu stuck at blackscreen after installation on a laptop with damaged discrete Radeon GPU

Tags: boot, drivers, radeon, amdgpu

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 on an old laptop whose discrete AMD Radeon GPU was blown up (probably due to heavy gaming). In Windows, the AMD GPU has to be disabled in device manager to prevent BSOD.

I could start Ubuntu LiveUSB and install Ubuntu on my computer without error. Yet after the installation completed and rebooted the computer just stuck at OEM logo.

I tried booting into LiveUSB again, adding "blacklist amdgpu" to /etc/modprobe.d and running "update-initramfs" with directory switched to the installed hard drive path using chroot. Yet that didn't solve the problem.

What else shall I do to block Ubuntu completely from detecting AMD GPU? Maybe I shall try blocking PCIe port of the damaged GPU?

Comment: Try google your laptop make and model with installing/removing GPU.  Might be easy or almost impossible, but think a damage GPU connected to power is not best idea.

Comment: Sadly there's no proper way to disconnect the damaged GPU physically. It is welded on the motherboard and the BIOS setting has no option to disable the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is blocking AMD Radeon device from Grub by adding "radeon.modeset=0" in /etc/default/grub then run update-grub